# What would be the highest normal form of this relation?

Tags: rdbms, database-normalization

Relation:    `R(ABCDE)`

FD:     `F = {AB-> CDE, A->CD}`

Solution: `CK = AB`

Prime Attribute = `A,B`
Non Prime Attribute = `C,D,E`

What normal form is `R` in?

Answer (score 0):

R(ABCDE) is in 1NF because it has only atomic data and violates 2NF's rule.

if we were to decompose R into relation R1(**A**,C,D), R2 (**A,B** ,E) then it would be in BCNF( or higher)

Note:

1. The relation is in Normal forms if it does not **violate** some rules, so theoretically R1, R2 are also in 4nf --they don't violate 4nf's condition-- and may be higher normal forms(I have no idea about them).
2. I said BCNF above instead of 4nf because it is in bcnf because of decomposition while it is in 4nf because it is too simple to violate 4nf's rules